# Unable to load HTTPS captcha using Flash on Samsung Smart TV

Tags: java, flash, tomcat, https, samsung-smart-tv

I developed a web app using **Java** and it is deployed under **Tomcat** configured to use **HTTPS**. It is working fine on browsers.

On the other hand, I have **a Flash application on Samsung Smart TV** which is communicating with my server. In case of HTTP mode works great. But it's unable to communicating on HTTPS.

**Something strange:**
The Flash application loads other HTTPS image resource as captcha around the web fine!

Would you please help me on this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the web server logs when the Flash app uses HTTPS? Do you even see the HTTPS requests from Flash in the web servers access log? Also, are you using a self signed cert?

Comment: No, I can't receive the request on server and there is no any track on log.
My certificate is self signed, I order a valid but it will be ok in 2 weeks. Is this because of certificate? Flash app on TV is able to load my not valid certificate HTTPS php captcha.

Answer (score 2):

Try running Https on port 443 and try loading Cross Domain Security Policy for Flash Movies for more Information visit here [Cross Domain Security Policy](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)

Flash will not work if the server includes a "no-cache" value in "Cache-Control" try editing that. also check your code base  address starts with Http or Https, if it starts with Http try making Https. You can check the codebase in embedded code of flash.

Comment: I'm going for Cross Domain Security Policy.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you're saying that images from other HTTPS source are working, it can't be Samsung side problem.

Did you check the headers of this generated captcha? Are they the same like in other working images?

Did other HTTPS sources that you check have valid SSL certificates? And what about yours?

Comment: All headers attribute are the same. And it works with both valid and invalid stranger's certificates.

Comment: What is the image type of captcha, can you send me direct link to it. So I can check it on my device.

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible. I'm working in a bank and they have restrict rules on publishing through the Internet.

Comment: try to running Https on port 443